# Why swap isn't in use enough on my system

Tags: linux, memory, debian, swap

I have Debian GNU/Linux 8.4 (jessie).
I have this output of free:

```
olga@olgacomp:~$ free -h
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:          2.0G       1.9G       104M       115M        24M       422M
-/+ buffers/cache:       1.4G       551M
Swap:         1.0G        54M       969M
```

My question is: why in my situation, when almost all memory used, swap filled just for 54M? Why system don't pushes more blocks there and frees the RAM?
I ask it because much time memory go be 99% busy, and swap is still almost free.

Comment: Why use swap when there is still space in ram?

Comment: Using the swap is slower then using RAM.  Why do you want your system to be slower?

Comment: you can adjust the system swappiness (the degree to which you use swap based on runtime conditions) if you like, but I would recommend against it since you have more than 25% free ram (remember, you subtract buffers and cache from used to get actual ram available to apps). https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/linux-swappiness/

Comment: Frank, thanx! I did it! Ramhoud and TheKB, I want tune it, because my computer stucking every time memory go be 99% full. However swap is empty.